# How do I lower my weapon in Halo 3?

Tags: halo-3

In machinima, such as Red vs. Blue, the characters carry their weapons lowered, rather than pointing straight ahead. How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for this I think:

**LB** + **RB** + **A** + **↓ D-Pad** + **Left Analog Click**

It's worth noting that this only works in Local or System Link games